# prepareForSegue equivalent in WatchKit based on rowindex

Tags: ios, watchkit

I've been trying to setup a hierarchical table in WatchKit based on the row that is selected.

I know this involves using `contextForSegueWithIdentifier`.

Can someone explain how selected row details are provided to the destination interface controller?

@IBOutlet var mainTable: WKInterfaceTable!

```
let mains = ["Full Schedule", "Custom Sched."]

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    loadTableData()
}

private func loadTableData() {

    mainTable.setNumberOfRows(mains.count, withRowType: "InterfaceTableRowController")

    for (index, mainName) in mains.enumerate() {

        let row = mainTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! InterfaceTableRowController

        row.interfaceLabel.setText(mainName)
    }

}

override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject?
{

    let mainName = mains[rowIndex]
    return mainName
}


override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    NSLog("%@ will activate", self)
}
```

OK So this is where I am at [as just one of my Controllers] and assume if I select full schedule, it'll display a list of thursday > Friday > Saturday > Sunday .... but If I choose custom it'll show Name > Name > Name > Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, it's slightly similar to `prepareForSegue` but you return a context to be passed to the destination interface controller, instead of directly setting a property on the destination interface controller.

1. In the source interface controller, you override `contextForSegueWithIdentifier`, and check the Storyboard `segueIdentifier` to determine which segue is taking place.
2. Next, you use the rowIndex to retrieve that row's data from its `mains` array.
3. Finally, you return that data which will be the context that the destination interface controller will access.

   In your example, you return a string which represents the selected type of schedule:

   ```
   override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject? {
       if segueIdentifier == "showSchedule" {
           return mains[rowIndex]
       }
       return nil
   }
   ```
4. In the destination interface controller, you access the context that was provided.

   In this case, it's the type of selected schedule.  You'd configure the array for that type of schedule, then populate the table.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var scheduleTable: WKInterfaceTable!

   override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
       super.awakeWithContext(context)

       // Configure table here.
       guard let context = context as? String else {
           return
       }

       // Load the table based on the type of (full or custom) schedule
       if context == "Full schedule" {
          loadFullSchedule()
       } else if context == "Custom Sched." {
          loadCustomSchedule()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: OK, so I'm *KIND OF* understanding this, so it's basically repopulating the new controller with one of the possible options, right?

So I added in my code I'm using on my 3rd screen, do you have time to apply your principles to my code & edits, just so I can fully grasp the idea of where your mind is at?

Comment: is there a specific tutorial or article about this I could use to read up and get better?

Comment: @conedmiro I've updated the example again.  Hopefully that will help you understand how the next controller determines what to show in its table.  Good luck!

Comment: Had to change my [Push] to [Modal]s and got it al lworking! I even see where it as confusing me at first [I had too much extra information pre-populated before I got your help!

Thank you so much!!!!